# php function call from drop down list and file upload

Tags: php, select

My website has the following code which is working to upload a file  when the user clicks the Upload file button, and it sends an email to a static email address.  However, I am trying to give the user the ability to select a recipient from a dropdown list.  I have found several ways to do both of these things separately, But I have not sure how to go about about setting $recipient to Person1 or Person2 @xyz.com in my call to the $mailer function and at the same time post the file upload.
I appreciate any help.

```
<?php if( !empty($upload_output) ): ?>    
<?php
// if not empty send one email
$subuser = $session->username;
$mailer->sendUploadNotice($subuser,$config,$recipient);
endif; ?>   


<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><b>Step 1</b> Choose file to upload: <input name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file[]" type="file" class="inputtext" /></p> 
<p><b>Step 2</b> Choose a recipient 
<select>
<option value="person1@xyz.com" selected>person1@example.com</option>
<option value="person2@xyz.com">person2@example.com</option>
</select> </p>
<p><b>Step 3</b> Click the Upload File button </p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: Give your select box a `name` attribute first so it will actually post, then use `$recipient = $_POST['your_select_name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if( !empty($upload_output) ): ?>    
<?php
// if not empty send one email
$recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
$subuser = $session->username;
$mailer->sendUploadNotice($subuser,$config,$recipient);
endif; ?>   


<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p><b>Step 1</b> Choose file to upload: <input name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file[]" type="file" class="inputtext" /></p> 
    <p><b>Step 2</b> Choose a recipient 
    <select name="recipient">
    <option value="person1@xyz.com" selected>person1@example.com</option>
    <option value="person2@xyz.com">person2@example.com</option>
    </select> </p>
    <p><b>Step 3</b> Click the Upload File button </p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
```

add a name to your `select` box and then use `$_POST` to get the value of the option selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a HTML Drop down from a DB try this

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `your table` ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){

        extract($row);
        //echo the row into option value, email in the value and display name in the display area
{
    $aa .= "<option value='{$row['email']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";

}
?>
```

This is how I populate my HTML drop down.

```
<select name="recipient" required>
        <option value="">Select Name</option>
        <?php echo$aa; ?></select>
```

Add this to the rest of your code and you should be good to go

Comment: most of my searches for dropdown and php resulted in posts about populating the dropdown from the database.  I wasn't trying to do that.  I only have a few choices but was having trouble with the concept of one button posting a recipient variable and initiating the file upload.